# How can I use sed to display the lines between the first blank line and the last line?

Tags: sed, zsh, curl

I'm trying to parse the response from my web server in a shell script. This is the response:

```
HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND
Content-Length: 223
Content-Type: application/json
Last-Modified: Fri, 21 Aug 2020 15:24:23 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=43200
Expires: Sat, 22 Aug 2020 08:04:19 GMT
ETag: "1598023463.02863-223-4034336499"
Date: Fri, 21 Aug 2020 20:04:19 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.8.5

{
    "message": {
        "status": "404",
        "message": "Not Found"
    }
}
```

I assigned this to a variable:

```
% foo="$(curl -i http://127.0.0.1/404)"
```

Instead of one variable, I want one for the status code and one for the response body. It's easy enough to grab the status code:

```
% echo "$foo" | head -n 1
```

The hard part is using sed to filter out the headers. Based on [Bruce Barnett's wonderful Sed grymoire](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-30), I thought this would work:

```
% echo "$foo" | sed '1,/^$/ d'
```

Or alternatively:

```
% echo "$foo" | sed -n '/^$/,$ p'
```

However, the result of both commands is nothing at all. I don't understand why.

In case it matters, I'm using zsh 5.8 and GNU sed 4.8 from Homebrew and curl 7.64.1 from Mac OS.

Comment: Are the lines blank or are there control-M characters in there? Try `echo "$foo" | hexdump -C`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to read the output of hexdump, but I did notice some carriage returns with `sed -n l`.

Comment: Yes, `echo "$foo" | tr -d '\r' | sed '1,/^$/d'` works :)

Comment: If the first line of input is empty and there are no more empty lines then you're toast. Safer to use `0,/^$/d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that there are carriage returns (CRs) in the output from curl, so patterns like `/^$/` never match as every line has a CR and so is not empty.

There are a couple of things that can be done, either remove the CRs or else account for them.

```
foo="$(curl -i http://127.0.0.1/404 | tr -d '\r')"
```

will remove them, and then

```
printf '%s\n' "$foo" | sed '1,/^$/d'
```

will work, or else use if I didn't remove the CRs using `tr`

```
printf '%s\n' "$foo" | sed $'1,/^\r$/d'
```

Since zsh can do string substitutions, I would tend to use

```
printf '%s\n' "${foo#*$'\r\n\r\n'}"
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' "${foo#*$'\n\n'}"
```

depending on if I had used `tr` to strip the CRs, to save the sed process.

There is a caveat however: command substitution strips *all* trailing newline characters (not carriage return ones). An HTTP response is `<header1>CRLF...<headern>CRLFCRLF<body>`. If the `<body>` is empty, `$foo` will contain only `<header1>CRLF...<headern>CRLFCR` or `<header1>CRLF...<headern>` if we've removed the CRs. In those cases, the `*$'\r\n\r\n'` or `*$'\n\n'` won't match and the headers won't be removed.

In any case, to print an arbitrary string followed by a newline character, the syntax is:

```
printf '%s\n' "$foo"  # POSIX
print -r - "$foo"     # ksh/zsh
echo -E - "$foo"      # zsh
```

Not <strike>`echo "$foo"`</strike> which doesn't work properly if `$foo` contains backslashes (common in json) or some values that start with `-` (shouldn't be the case for json).

Answer (score 3):

Headers are required by RFC7230 to be separated by CR-LF pairs, then a pair of CRLF (CRLF - CRLF) (in loose terms: an empty line), then the HTTP response "body". Thus, a normal http/1.1 will contain some **carriage return**.

There is no "empty line" as Unix describe it, that is, no pair of `\n\n` ends the headers. That also means that for sed, a `^$` will not match the empty (DOS) line at the end of the headers, as that line contain a `\r` (Carriage Return). In (GNU) sed, an alternative to detect this (almost) empty line could be `^\r$`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$foo" | sed '1,/^\r$/ d'
```

#### Remove carriage returns

If it is valid to remove the carriage return characters, an http response (the whole http/1.1 message that the server will emit)  will have empty lines as two consecutive newlines (`\n\n`) to separate headers from body.

If so, the special value of a null `RS` (paragraph mode in awk) could deal with this headers:

```
$ echo "$foo" | tr -d '\r' | awk -v RS="" 'NR>1'
```

Or, to ensure that empty lines in the body of the email are preserved:

```
$ echo "$foo" | tr -d '\r' | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="\n\n"}NR>1'
```

#### Allow carriage return

However, mail (as in RFC5322) and http responses (the whole http/1.1 message as in RFC7230) are required to use `CR NL` as the [end of line marker for headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230). An RS that could contain an **optional** carriage return requires a regular expression and the use of the RT (record terminator) as it is not constant. That means that GNU awk should be used.

```
$ echo "foo" | awk 'BEGIN{RS="(\r?\n){2}"}NR>1{printf "%s%s",$0,RT}'
{
    "message": {
        "status": "404",
        "message": "Not Found"
    }
}
```